# Maintain sessions with zerorpc

Tags: python, zeromq, zerorpc

How do I maintain different sessions or local state with my [zerorpc](http://zerorpc.dotcloud.com/) server?

For example (below), if I have a multiple clients, subsequent clients will overwrite the model state. I thought about each client having an ID, and the RPC logic will try to separate the variables that way, but tbis seems messy and how would I clear out old states/variables once the clients disconnect?

**Server**

```
import zerorpc
import FileLoader

class MyRPC(object):
    def load(self, myFile):
        self.model = FileLoader.load(myFile)
    def getModelName(self):
        return self.model.name

s = zerorpc.Server(MyRPC())
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")
s.run()
```

**Client 1**

```
import zerorpc

c = zerorpc.Client()
c.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242")
c.load("file1")
print c.getModelName()
```

**Client 2**

```
import zerorpc

c = zerorpc.Client()
c.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242")
c.load("file2") # AAAHH! The previously loaded model gets overwritten here! 
print c.getModelName()
```

Comment: I really wished this question had been properly answered. There seems to be no trivial way to access the underlying zeromq sessions, which could likely help maintaining additional state to each session. Maybe the good-ol' session token will have to do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about sessions...but if you want to get back different models? Maybe you could just have once function that instantiates a new Model()?

```
import zerorpc
import FileLoader

models_dict ={}  # Keep track of our models

def get_model(file):
    if file in models_dict:
        return models_dict[file]
    models_dict[file] = MyModel(file)
    return model

class MyModel(object):

    def __init__(self, file):
        if file:
            self.load(file)

    def load(self, myFile):
        self.model = FileLoader.load(myFile)

    def getModelName(self):
        return self.model.name

s = zerorpc.Server(<mypackagename.mymodulename>)  # Supply the name of current package/module
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")
s.run()
```

Client:

```
import zerorpc

c = zerorpc.Client()
c.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242")
print c.get_model("file1")
```